# Broken links resulting from php include references

Tags: broken-links, php-include

I'm learning php but am up against a wall right now with a referencing issue. I've searched a lot but I can't find any posts with my exact structural problem. Hoping to master this hurdle so I can move toward the next...

My basic file structure something like:

```
domain.com/
        home.php
        images/
                global/
                        nav/
                            nav-img.jpg
        includes/
                menu.php
        fruit/
                apples/
                        red/
                            gala/
                                gala.php
```

I want to create a global path establishing my web root directory that I can reference on the fly in each page wherever it resides. BUT other posts on this general topic give [10] different functions I can use. I just want [1]. Also, I don't know where to put [for example] define(ROOT), or how to call it from an individual page.

*Will define(ROOT) work for my situation?*

---

Knowing that all pages use [menu.php], my obstacle:

From  gala/gala.php  - when I click on [home], it looks for:

```
/fruit/apples/red/gala/home.php  [does not exist, of course!]
```

---

*Also, trying to **AVOID** these [2] things if possible:*

**I.** Using html file references in **gala.php** like this:  ../../../../includes/menu.php

to find the correct global include.

**II.** And avoid using link references in **menu.php** like this:  /images/global/nav/nav-img.jpg

Any feedback would be appreciated [+] or [-]. Thanks a lot.

Comment: PROCEDURAL OR OOP way of PHP i think avoiding those 2 things at the same time isn`t possibble. since its still needed to declare the value of your target location.

Comment: really,? I thought that's what defining the root was for? So, you can make an easier/simpler and portable reference to a file like `define('ROOT','some/path')` and then call the file with something like include() or require() `require('ROOT.filename')`. Am I totally wrong here? I'm obviously missing something...

Comment: also, I'm not married to that. Just was a preference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I did that seemed the best:

For **I. and II.** to avoid using so many ../../../../
in all the **src**="" and **href**=""  I just settled and used site-relative file references with **leading slashes**, such as "/includes/menu.php" which would get me to the site root, building the file's location from there.

For the **global file reference**, BOTH of these worked:

```
<?php 
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/";
?> 
// in `<head>` section
```

And using `<?php include ('menu.php'); ?>`

OR THIS ONE WORKED TOO:

```
<?php 
define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); 
define('INCLUDES',ROOT.'/includes/'); 
?>  
// in `<head>` section
```

And using `<?php include (INCLUDES.'menu.php'); ?>` in a file at another level.