# images broken when included

Tags: html

This probably has a simple answer, but I've had no luck searching so far.

I have two php pages, index.php and headerBake.php. headerBake.php is included in index.php and everything looks the way it should except that two small images (a twitter icon and facebook icon) are broken. The images are referenced and linked in headerBake.php and the file paths for the icons are correct.

My questions are:

Do I have to include the icons in separate includes in order to get them to show up? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Does my problem have to do with [global paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399758/broken-links-resulting-from-php-include-references)?

My code-

headerBake.php:

```
<link href="bakery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <header class="header" role="banner">
      <div id="innerHeader">
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.html">Auntie Jane's Bakery and Catering</a></div>
        <div id="socialPhone">
          <div id="socialIcons">
            <a href="http://facebook.com">
              <img src="LogoSocial/social_facebook_box_blue.png" width="24px" /></a>
            <a href="http://twitter.com">
              <img src="LogoSocial/Twitter-Icon.png" width="27px" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="clear-div"></div>
          <div id="bakeryNumber">Order online or Call: #860-538-8900</div>
          <div class="clear-div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-div"></div>
      </div>
      <ul id="navBar">
        <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="weddingcakes">Wedding Cakes</a></li>
            <li><a href="celebrationcakes">Celebration Cakes</a></li>
            <li><a href="cupcakes">Cupcakes</a></li>
            <li><a href="cookies">Cookies</a></li>
            <li><a href="brownies">Brownies</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="catering.html">Catering</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
```

index.php

```
<body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="indexContent">
          <div class="slideshow"></div>
          <div class="clear-div"></div>
          <div class="newscolumn"></div>
          <div class="clear-div"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <footer>
      <div id="sitemap">
        <div id="menu">
          <p><h4>SiteMap:</h4>
          <br />
          Menu:<br />
          Wedding Cakes | Celebration Cakes<br />
          Cupcakes | Cookies | Brownies<br />
          About Us | Catering | Contact Us
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="address">
          <p>We are located at:<br />
            123 Parker Lane<br />
            Hartford, CT 06103 
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-div"></div>
      </div>
    </footer>
</body>
    </html>
```

EDIT: All my files, including the icon images, are now all in the same place:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/39QKK.jpg

Surprise, I still have broken image links.

Comment: What is your project structure?

Comment: learn how to use `./` and `../` to form proper relative paths. And this should really only be tagged HTML. You've got HTML in PHP files, yes, but PHP is not involved in the issue at all.

Comment: It's likely an issue of where the include is relative to where your index is. You'd probably be best off giving them absolute paths.

Comment: First, the closing `</body>` tag sholud be after (and not before) your `<footer>...</footer>` tag... Then, do a right click on the broken image and select `open image in new tab`.. Is the image path really well defined?

Comment: @gmo when I open one of the broken images in a new tab I get an "Access forbidden!" error, but not "object not found!" (like I would expect if the file path was wrong). So I'm at a loss.

Comment: There you go then... `403 error ≈ 404 error` in ***this situation***, you must fix that server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having fixed the malformed code, and verified the direct access to the images, with a 403 error response in your browser...

```
http://localhost/Bakery/logodesign1.png
```

*You get `Error 403` (Forbidden)*
So the problem must rely in the server...

Try the following in the terminal to change permissions: <sub>(as I see in your screenshot, you're in OS & XAMPP)</sub>

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Bakery
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

now try again:

```
 http://localhost/Bakery/logodesign1.png
```

*must get a `Error 200` now, which is fine*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your image is located at (mywebsite)/LogoSocial/(Icon).png, try changing the image links to:

```
<img src="/LogoSocial/<icon>.png" ... >
```

The leading slash says 'start looking for this object at the root level of your website'.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your php code. It's all about absolute and relative paths.

If your path start with a leading slash `/`, the browser will try to fetch the ressource from the root directory.
If it doesn't start wit a slash, the link will be considered as a relative path.

For example, let's suppose your `index.php` is located here `http://domain.com/blah/index.php`.

- The link `LogoSocial/social_facebook_box_blue.png` which is a
  **relative path** to your current ressource (`http://domain.com/blah/index.php`) will lead to :

  `http://domain.com/blah/LogoSocial/social_facebook_box_blue.png`
- On the other hand, this **absolute path**
  `/LogoSocial/social_facebook_box_blue.png` (notice the leading slash)
  will lead to :

  `http://domain.com/LogoSocial/social_facebook_box_blue.png`

  *The root directory for this case would be `http://domain.com/`*.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you're trying to load your images relative to where your headerBake.php file is.

When you use PHP to include a file, just imagine that the code from the file is copied and pasted into the index.php.

PHP is a server side language, and in this case, is responsible for generating a HTML response. Once the response is generated and returned back to the browser, the browser has no idea which PHP files were used, and where they are located.

Your images need to be accessible by the browser e.g. http://example.com/img/something.png. As other people have recommended, I would use an absolute path rather than a relative path.